# How to use nify javascript to make round corner box? Im using but not working

Tags: javascript, css, rounded-corners

How to make round corners with Nifty technique. I included niftycube.js and then called the function Nifty("div.firstblock");. But its not working. Whether i have to include any other JavaScript or CSS??. Help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include the niftyCorners.css as well.

Answer (score 2):

Please stop, it's not worth your time. Firefox, Safari, Chrome and Konqueror all support their own form of the CSS3 style, `border-radius`, so put this in your CSS and be done with it:

```
.myDiv {
    -moz-border-radius: 5px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 5px;
    border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Giving your divs rounded corners is just a visual nicety and one that can be saved for people with modern browsers. If IE users don't get a rounded border, **so what?**

Comment: Thanks for this, I was getting really mad cuz nifty never worked for me and border-radius works like a charm!